# Bash script to convert the 2nd column in csv file from Unix time to readable date / time

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, csv, conversion

My input file is a comma separated .csv.
I'd like to convert the 2nd columns from unix time to a readable date time format like this...

```
before   1502280000
after    8/10/17 08:00:00
```

I'd also like to ignore the first row as it is headers.

I'm running in a bash shell on Solaris 10

the first two rows of my csv look like this

```
HOST,DATE_TIME_CREATED,USER_ID,EVENT_CLASS
xxxx,1502286180,xxxx,xxxx
xxxx,1502280347,xxxx,xxxx
```

looking for output of

```
HOST,DATE_TIME_CREATED,USER_ID,EVENT_CLASS
xxxx,Wed Aug  9 09:43:00 EDT 2017,xxxx,xxxx
xxxx,Wed Aug  9 08:05:47 EDT 2017,xxxx,xxxx
```

Comment: How does `1502280000` convert to `8/10/17 08:00:00`.  Can you clarify the format of your source date with something like so: `YYMMDDHHMM`

Comment: my source data is a unix date time stamp if I use format-unix clock at the cmd line I get the readable time

Comment: [mvf@radwhtdb01:/usr/mvf/bin] $  format-unix-clock 1502280000
Wed Aug  9 08:00:00 EDT 2017

Comment: @JeffC, `Wed Aug 9` is not `8/10/17` at all

Comment: It will be better, if you put input and desired output data examples in to your question.

Comment: It's an `EPOCH` date value which is seconds since January 1, 1970 UTC.   You should be able to simply convert it with `date -r 1502280000 "+%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"` (I know you need to do some other line manipulation first but I can't even confirm the solaris command to convert it at the moment.)  I have access to a SmartOS machine which is based on Solaris 10~ but none of the commands I'm finding work on it.

Comment: the first two rows of my csv look like this    HOST,DATE_TIME_CREATED,USER_ID,EVENT_CLASS

Comment: can you try `format-unix-clock 1502280000 "+%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"` Shot in the dark but also does the `date -r 1502280000 "+%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"` work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly recommend the time format YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS -- that format is unambiguous, and it sorts lexically and chronologically.

You can use perl for this:

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -F, -ane '
    $F[1] = strftime("%F %T", localtime $F[1]) if $. > 1; 
    print join ",", @F
' file
```

Comment: thanks glenn this looks great, now i just need to overwrite my input file, with the new data, instead of printing to the screen.

Comment: That's easy: `perl -i -M....`

Answer (score 1):

The `awk` approach:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{printf"%s,",$1;
             system("printf \"$(date -d @"$2")\"");printf",%s,%s\n",$3,$4}
' infile.txt
```

```
HOST,DATE_TIME_CREATED,USER_ID,EVENT_CLASS
xxxx,Wed Aug  9 09:43:00 EDT 2017,xxxx,xxxx
xxxx,Wed Aug  9 08:05:47 EDT 2017,xxxx,xxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (`mlr`) to format the Unix timestamp using `strftime_local()`.  Note that the generated time+date is in the local timezone:

```bash
$ mlr --csv put '$DATE_TIME_CREATED = strftime_local($DATE_TIME_CREATED,"%c")' file
HOST,DATE_TIME_CREATED,USER_ID,EVENT_CLASS
xxxx,Wed Aug  9 13:43:00 2017,xxxx,xxxx
xxxx,Wed Aug  9 12:05:47 2017,xxxx,xxxx
```

See the `strftime(3)` manual on your system for formatting strings you can use.  The `%c` format "is replaced by national representation of time and date".